# how to get with powershell the list items which have old versions of a workflow running

Tags: 2013, workflow, powershell

I have in the following screenshot many workflows, but some of them are abandoned by the users and I need to identify which ones.  As I cant install sharepoint designer, then I need to do this with powershell

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check [SPWorkflow.Created](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflow.created.aspx) of the workflow instances

Here are the steps for the script:

1. Loop through all the items and get the running workflows

   ```
   $workflows = $item.Workflows
   ```
2. For every workfow instance check the creation date and compare it with the datetime of the last workflow version (from your screenshot)

   ```
   $workflow.Created
   ```

That way you should be able to detect the items which have old workflow versions running